# Is my code using the optimal way to read standard input in php?

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, stdin

I am using PHP CLI to provide standard input. Am I using the optimal method of reading that input?

For example, I will provide it 50,000 lines of data. Each line contains two numbers. Is my code below the most efficient way to read 50,000 lines of data? Or this a very inefficient way to do so?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Testing time period for execution

// Time tracker: TESTING
$micropoint1 = microtime(true);

// First, retrieve the number of points that will be provided.
$no_points = fgets(STDIN);

for($i=1, $max=$no_points+1; $i<$max; $i++) {
    list($x, $y) = fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d"); // Get the string returned from the command line and convert to an array
}

// Time tracker: TESTING
$micropoint2 = microtime(true);
$pointelapsed = $micropoint2 - $micropoint1; 


fwrite(STDOUT, "\nPoint Loop Took ".$pointelapsed." microsecs\n");



?>
```

Comment: Let me know if further clarification of the code is needed and I can be more descriptive as to how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine your approach getting any more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To be more efficient, it's better to:

1. Make your "%d %d" into single quotes '%d %d'
2. Move this string into variable/constant and use it in 50000 loop

Answer (score 0):

As it is clearly very minimal and cannot be nerfed any further. However, since you didn't specify, that you want to optimize the loop only. Then I few points for the rest of the code.

When displaying the microtime, you can do this:

```
$pointelapsed = number_format(microtime(true) - $micropoint1, 7);
```

And also, what happens if `fscanf()` cant return anything. Wouldn't it give out an error..?